# What does [\n*] mean?

Tags: tr

I am trying to learn Bash and I was wondering what the following line means:

```
errors=($(tr -c '[:alpha:]' '[\n*]' < "$word" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'))
```

I know that `tr -c` replaces anything not alpha with `\n*`, but I don't know what `\n*` is. I've been looking around at the internet for a while, can someone help?

Also, I am new to Bash and C.

Comment: `\n` is the new line character (ascii 10). From `man tr`:  [CHAR*] in SET2, copies of CHAR until length of SET1

Answer (score 0):

See the [`tr` man page](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/tr1.html)

```
   [CHAR*]
              in SET2, copies of CHAR until length of SET1
```